# How can I test VIM's Features?

Tags: vim

*The features seen with the command ":version" raised my interest.*

I am particularly interested in the features, such as Ruby, Python and Emacs-tags. I cannot find instructions in the manuals. I found a command "--with-features=huge", after some googling, but it does not show how to really install the features. I have used Vim over a year, so I am rather flabbergasted of the features. I have installed things, such as Taglist. What is the main difference to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly are you asking. "Vim's features, perhaps all" is a term which can be taken in a very wide context.

If you're interested in scripting, either in vimscript, or Python, Ruby ... download an install vim's standalone installer - it comes with a precompiled support for those. Of course, you still need to have Python, Ruby ... installed.

If you're interested in vim's general features, like editing text, macros, plugins, support for this and that ... i.e. vim in general, well I could only suggest a tutorial off the net or a [book](http://iccf-holland.org/click5.html). I gave a few links for tutorials below:

[Vim Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)
[Vim Tutorial](http://www.linuxconfig.org/Vim_Tutorial)
[Vi and Vim editor](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html)
[Best of vim tips](http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html?dupe=with_honor)
[Quick ref. card](http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vimqrc.html)
[Learning vim](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_vi:Vim)
... anyway, the net's full of them

What do you mean under compiling ? I'm not gonna try guessing, but try these:

```
:help make
:help makeprg
```

Refine your question.

Comment: I have the book "Learning the Vi and Vim editors, O'Reilly, English". There is no index entry for the thing "feature". I cannot understand the jargon. What are the "features" shown with the command ":version"? How can I find them in the book?

Comment: No, I don't think there should be either. It will just confuse people. That is something concerning developers, not regular users (I'm not sure why are you even bothering yourself with it). Vim comes in many flavours, and therefore can be compiled&built with some options enabled and some not. For example, I'm pretty sure I'll personally never need arabic support. So, I compile my built of vim without it. Now, since usually some group of people need some group of options, you call one version of vim's build "tiny", one, i don't know, "normal" ?, and one "full features" ...

Comment: If I remember correctly standalone binaries installer which can be downloaded from vim's site has pretty much you could ever need in working with vim.

Comment: Also, most of the features you see with ":version" can be looked up in vim's help with ":help arabic", ":help autocmd" and so on. Vim's help is very through, and I suggest learning how to use it properly, since it can answer many questions.

Comment: +1 and accepted because of the issue concerning developers

Answer (score 11):

The "features" you're referring to are Vim's build-time features. Think of these features as options you can get when you buy a car. For example, many cars come in a 4-door or 2-door version. You need to specifiy up-front which one you want, and you can't change your mind later on unless you want to get a new car. Likewise, you can't change the compile-time options in Vim without building a new binary.

A lot of these features are also mutually exclusive. For example, you can't enable both the motif and gnome versions of the gui simultaneously. (just like you can't have a car that's both 4-door and 2-door)

Also, some of the feature are OS-specific. For example, you aren't going to get the "amiga" feature unless you're running Vim on an Amiga.

That said, most pre-built binaries of Vim that you're likely to come across will have the majority of interesting features enabled. You can use `:version` to find out which features are enabled in your build of vim. Once you've done that, take a look at `:help feature-list` (scroll down a bit) for a list of the features along with links to relevant documentation for each feature.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if you are new to vim I'd just install the binary.

Usually extra vim features are added by custom scripts and plugins rather then by compiling them in. Just install vim and then use the excellent [Vim tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) to find and add extras you'd like to have.

Good luck :)